# outlook 365 distribution list overqualified

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, outlook-web-app

I need to issue an alias for a set of email addresses of our external partners-clients that a group of our employees use to send mail to so they don't have to pick them one by one each time. Locally on each online outlook or desktop outlook this can be done but we have to do it in each account. Centrally using office 365 admin console it allows for a distribution list but it has more features than I need. I just want to give an alias to a bunch of email addresses and only people in a team of employees can access that alias. I don't want collaboration features and features that the central admin console offers when you create a distribution list. Requires creating an email address (even if virtual) and sending list members an initial email that they are now members of the group. This will confuse our customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing Microsoft 365 groups with the older Distribution Groups.
Distribution will simply distribute the incoming e-mail the all the members. No collaboration features are available for these type of groups.

To create a distribution list follow these steps:

1. Select the app launcher icon and choose Admin.
2. Select Groups > Groups in the left navigation pane, and then select Add a group.
3. On the Choose a group type field, choose Distribution, and then choose Next.
4. Enter a name, description, and email alias for your new group, and choose whether you want people outside your organization to send email to the group.
5. Press Add to create a group, and then review your group and choose Close.

To Add members to the group follow these steps:

1. In the admin center, go to the Groups > Groups page.
2. On the Groups page, select the name of the group you want to add a contact to.
3. On the Members tab, select View all and manage members.
4. On the View Members page, select Add members, and select the user or contact you want to add to the distribution group.

If you want the group only be available for specific sources you should be able to block/allow certain senders using the mail flow rules.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/create-distribution-lists?view=o365-worldwide
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/email/add-user-or-contact-to-distribution-list?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 0):

> Locally on each online outlook or desktop outlook this can be done but we have to do it in each account.

Do it on one client and then share the contact list with the other accounts via email. You can refer to the detailed instructions in the link below:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-a-contact-group-or-distribution-list-with-others-8233771f-4d37-4140-af83-fb5fea9ecba1

Comment: And every time a change is made to the list should this be done? This is not a practical solution. And I don't want contacts generated from those emails to build a distribution list. I only want a nickname for the list which can be managed centrally.

Comment: It would be very helpful if they explained to us the reasons why some gave a negative rating to the question.

Comment: >> And every time a change is made to the list should this be done?

Yes, this is the drawback of the method...